# Snap slides extending screen width to center using CSS scroll snapping

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a slider where each slide is wider than the viewport, but the center of each slide snaps to the center of the viewport. So the "Slide" words should align to the center of the screen. This is what I have:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.scroller {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}
.slide {
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 160vw;
  width: 160vw;

  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slide:nth-child(even) {
  background: #aa4;
}
.slide:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #4aa;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="scroller">
      <div class="slide slide-1">Slide</div>
      <div class="slide slide-2">Slide</div>
      <div class="slide slide-3">Slide</div>
      <div class="slide slide-4">Slide</div>
      <div class="slide slide-5">Slide</div>
      <div class="slide slide-6">Slide</div>
      <div class="slide slide-7">Slide</div>
    </div>
```

But unexpectedly, the slides snap to the beginning and end of the viewport. What do I need to change?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/blissful-wescoff-97qx26?file=%2Findex.html

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the text in any *tag* and set `margin-left` as your preference *50%* is working. you can change the value and remove the `justify-content: center;`  from *class* `.slide`.

Here is solution:

```css
Wrap the text in any tag and set margin-left as your preference but 30% is working. you can change the value and remove the justify-content: center;  from class .slide.

Here is solution:

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.scroller {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}
.slide {
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 160vw;
  width: 160vw;

  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}
.slide:nth-child(even) {
  background: #aa4;
}
.slide:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #4aa;
}

h2 {
  margin-left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="slide slide-1"><h2>Slide</h2></div>
  <div class="slide slide-2"><h2>Slide</h2></div>
  <div class="slide slide-3"><h2>Slide</h2></div>
  <div class="slide slide-4"><h2>Slide</h2></div>
  <div class="slide slide-5"><h2>Slide</h2></div>
  <div class="slide slide-6"><h2>Slide</h2></div>
  <div class="slide slide-7"><h2>Slide</h2></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a good solution. The text is not centered within the slide anymore, and will not be centered when the slide snaps to the end of the viewport.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem I have. I need the center of each slide to snap to the center of the container. Your proposal does something completely different, it's just centering the content of the slide within the viewport.